# kafka start up failed due to no auth issue

Tags: apache-kafka

I've a single node cluster setup of Apache kafka_2.12-2.5.1 (embedded zookeeper) on the same host. Enabled SSL on Zookeeper and it starts just fine. Kafka, however, throws fatal error "NoAuth for /brokers/ids" at start up.
Please help out if you've any pointers.

Comment: Did you specify super user in server.properties? Did you specify that user in KafkaServer as well as KafkaClient? It looks like you have ACL permissions issue here. :)

Comment: Thank you, no I didn't specify super user. I will surely do it. Appreciate your response.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. Note that I'm setting up SSL only between Zookeeper and Kafka Brokers, NOT consumer/producer to Kafka Brokers. I thought super user is required in latter?

Comment: Would you try to set it up without SSL first? As I said, you are likely having issues with ACL authorization. I specified `super.users=User:myuser` and then created that SCRAM user in Kafka and basically this user has no restrictions on anything. What helped me are these links https://www.ru-rocker.com/2020/05/22/how-to-secure-confluent-kafka-with-ssl-and-sasl-scram/ and https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/kafka/sasl.html#sasl-configuration-for-kafka-brokers but your use-case might be different. P.S. I am relatively new to Kafka.